# Request was aborted

Tags: asp.net, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I tried to split large file into small 4KB chunks and send each chunks to oracle cloud but request is aborting. Please check the splitting code whether it is correct or not or am I doing wrong something else.

```
FileStream rdr = new FileStream(fileToUpload, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] inData = new byte[4096];
long  chunkSize= rdr.Length;
long chunkBytesToRead = chunkSize;

using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    while (rdr.Position < rdr.Length)
    {
        int chunkBytesRead = 0;
        int maxread = 4096;

        while (chunkBytesRead < chunkSize)
        {
            int bytesRead = rdr.Read(inData,0,maxread);

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            reqStream.Write(inData, 0, bytesRead);

            chunkBytesToRead -= bytesRead;
            if (chunkBytesToRead < 4096)
                maxread = (int)chunkBytesToRead;

            chunkBytesRead += bytesRead;            
        }
    }

    reqStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: 4096 bytes is 4 kilobytes not 4 megabytes

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? At first glance, it seems like you are deducting from `chunkBytesToRead` which is 0, so it will be negative, and then you assign it to `maxread`.